# How do we usually process sequences in Java?

Tags: java, iterator, sequence

In C++, iterators in STL is very useful. I can write container independent code to process sequences.

However, I found `Iterator` and `ListIterator` are very poor in Java. They even don't support `clone()`. I think it's impossible to process sequences with them.

The only way to do this seems to be using arrays forever, but how can I reuse my code when I change arrays to `List`s ?

---

Processing sequences is to do some algorithms on a sequences of `Object`s. For example, sorting them , finding the maximun, remove duplicated items.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking, or perhaps just what you mean by "process a sequence", since people use iterators all the time to process sequences. There are certainly other options, like any of the functional-style things. Can you make your complain more specific?

Comment: "They even don't support clone()" - why would they want to?

Comment: What problems (other than not being able to call clone()) have you encountered with those classes?  What behavior are you expecting and why?

Comment: I'm guessing he's trying to work with a List of items and is frustrated that he doesn't have the control over Iterators in Java that he did in C++.

Comment: ... or perhaps that Java is not C++ ;)

Comment: Re your edit; there are *many* libraries that implement that--they're not part of the JDK itself. Well, there's `sort`, of course.

Comment: I know there are many libraries. But I want to write my own. And make it work on different containers.

Comment: @Mr.Phone If you don't `@` a name, the person you're responding to may never know you've said anything. Please be specific regarding what's stopping you--since there are many libraries, and you're aware of them, obviously you know it's possible. Although it's not clear to me what `clone` has to do with anything so far. Again--without providing specificity, it's unclear what information you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Type> list = new List<Type>
//add the elements...

for(Type t : list)
   //do you stuff with t
```

Normally you will not need to use the iterators explicitly in Java. Also, be careful with .clone() as it is rarely the most appropriate solution.

List itself is a interface that is implemented by different containers.

Comment: List itself is a interface that is implemented by different containers.

Comment: Rather than comment on your own post, put it in the post.

Comment: Maybe I should use "abstract containers", not "abstract iterators".

Answer (score 0):

I would use List<Type>, and avoid clone() as it doesn't always do what you think. i.e. it can be shallow or deep depending on the implementation.

List is a basic class. Perhaps if you give an example of what you are having trouble with it we can help you with that.